# Wrong response while sending AJAX post in PHP MVC project

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with PHP and homemade MVC framework. When I am sending an AJAX POST request I don't receive the correct response from the server. Instead I receive the beginning of my HTML page (navbar, logo, etc.).

```
function fetch_select(val) {
    $.post("fetch_profession.php", {}, function(data){
        $("#new_select").val(data);
    })
}
```

```html
<?php
    echo "Message from server";
?>
```

The jQuery code is in page with select list and react on change in list. The PHP code in in file `fetch_profession.php` and it try to only display message. I think the problem is with the routing in MVC, I test this script separately and everything works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the response in the network tab of the console. If you are receiving a HTML response instead of the text you expect it generally means that the server is giving you an error page back, either a 404 or 500 of some variety.

Comment: I am receiving the html of navbars and logo components.

Comment: If you check all the HTML it will be the template you have setup, populated with an error message somewhere. Until you can tell us exactly what the error is we can't really help you

Comment: I don't receive any error. In console I see POST was send and I see the response is my 2 first components (HTML files) with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add **ob_start();** before you return the value in your PHP file. This will remove the header part HTML and return only the output. If it is not working then try **ob_clean();** with the above code.

Also use **die;** at the end of your PHP file.

eg:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo 'some text';
die;
?>
```